# Comparing AD sites and SCCM boundaries

Tags: powershell

I m trying to compare the Active directory sites with SCCM boundaries, by using the below powershell scripts, but its not giving the output as expected.
There are 3 AD sites actually available in SCCM, however the script gives me an output that there is no AD sites available in SCCM boundaries.

```
$sites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites 
$CMBoundary = Get-CMBoundary | select value 
foreach ($adsite in $sites.name) { 
   foreach ($cmb in $CMBoundary.value ) { 
       if (($cmb | select value) -eq ($adsite | select name)) { 
           "$adsite available in CM" 
            } 
            else { "$adsite is NOT in CM $cmb" } 
            } 
     }
```

Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: $sites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites
$CMBoundary = Get-CMBoundary | select value

foreach ($adsite in $sites.name)
{
foreach ($cmb in $CMBoundary.value )
{
 if (($cmb | select value) -eq ($adsite | select name))
 { "$adsite available in CM" }
 else {  "$adsite is NOT in CM $cmb" }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Think I see the issue.

On line 3, you're selecting the `.Name` property from `$sites` and storing it in `$adsite`, for each step of your loop.

```
foreach ($adsite in $sites.name) {
```

However, you then also attempt to take the `.Name` property again, with this line:

```
if (($cmb | select value) -eq ($adsite | select name))
```

This won't work.  You've set `$adsite` to be equal to whatever was in `$sites.Name`, but that doesn't give a `.Name` property to `$adsite`.

Try this again, this time with the second Select statement removed. The reason this was failing is that there wouldn't be anything to compare against.  I've revised your code to remove this logic, let me know if it works.

```
 foreach ($adsite in $sites.name) { 
   foreach ($cmb in $CMBoundary.value ) { 
       if ($cmb -eq $adsite) { 
           "$adsite available in CM" 
            } 
            else { "$adsite is NOT in CM $cmb" } 
            } 
     }
```

Be warned, however, that if your boundary name doesn't exactly match an AD Site name, that this code will give you a lot of false positives.